# How to get the gRPC server IP from Go client

Tags: go, grpc

I use docker-compose or kubernetes to deploy my gRPC servers, and want to get the server IP address in the go client. Does the gRPC library provides the get server-side IP method?

BTW, the scenario here is that i want to log the server ip to check whether nginx, envoy and other L7 load balancers make correct routing decisions.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, as you already have knowledge about the gRPC server address prior to a client creation

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(*serverAddr)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
defer conn.Close()
client := pb.NewRouteGuideClient(conn)
```

I don't believe there is a method for getting server IP in the standard gRPC library. If you use external load balancers/proxies (e.g. Nginx or Envoy) you can add the end server IP to the metadata on the server side

```
md := metadata.Pairs(
    "serverIP", "127.0.0.1",
)
```

> The LB distributes the RPC call to one
>   of the available backend servers that implement the actual logic for
>   serving the call. The LB keeps track of load on each backend and
>   implements algorithms for distributing load fairly. The clients
>   themselves do not know about the backend servers.
>   read more https://grpc.io/blog/loadbalancing

Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is a higher level abstraction, you shouldn't deal with networking using RPC.

If you're trying to implement client side load balancing you should consider load balancing within gRPC (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md), which is a special protocol you have to implement.

Comment: The reason for getting the server ip is that i'm testing grpc traffic load balancer by using Nginx or Envoy on both docker-compose and kubernetes. So i need to print the server ip address to check whether the load balancer works. And i just want to know whether the grpc library has method to get the server ip after connection is being created.

Comment: this is pretty reasonable, I updated my answer according to your comments, unfortunately  you have to track the servers yourself

Comment: I'm now setting the server ip addr in the response header.

Comment: Once you set `GODEBUG=http2debug=2` on the client side, would the http2 logs contain this information ?

Answer (score -1):

you can define a custom picker, like round-robin [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_item_allocation).

The struct `map[balancer.SubConn]SubConnInfo` can be used when you pick an address, allowing you to get `SubConnInfo`.